# How to handle vue composition api with lazy and route components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue application I have a component page that contains five components. I also use [vue composition api](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com/).

each component is lazy, it resolve when the component is in the viewport. because of that I need to write the logic only inside the component. (not in the parent).

so far so good, but two of components inside `product.vue`  depend of the route params value. say `/product/2`.

the `product.vue` looks like that:

- `<intro>` -> just a raw text (no need to fetch from the server, not need to wait to load)
- `<foo>` -> need data from the server base on the `productId` from the `route.params`.
- `<txt>` -> just a raw text not need to get the data from the server
- `<bar>` -> need data from the server base on the `productId` from the `route.params`.

Important notes:

1. In case I don't need data from the server like intro I want to render it immediately. so for all similar components in this page.

   for example `intro` render right way, the `foo` will render when it enter to the viewport and display a loader and when the data is resolved it change to the data.
2. I want to see the page ASAP. so each component have its own loader.

Here I become with some problems:

One: I need to know if the product exist. if not it need to be redirect to 404 page. so where to put this logic? each component or the parent component? I think the parent component, but when it take 2 min to load the data I'll get a blank screen seince the components are not ready and not be render. which is conflict with "Important notes".

Two: when the `productId` is change (navigate to another product) the `foo` and `bar` need to resolve the data, so in those two components I need to listen to the route change (which makes duplication in my code) (and slow performance?) and still I need to check if the `productId` is exist or not.

in this example the items don't change because it need to trigger the `useProduct` function.

```
setup() {

  const { route, router } = useRouter();
    
  const productIdToLoad = computed(() => route.value.params.productId);

  const { items } = useProduct({ productId: productIdToLoad });

  return { items }

}
```

and if I do it in watch I lose the reference

```
setup() {
    
      const { route, router } = useRouter();
      const items = ref([]);
        
      const productIdToLoad = computed(() => route.value.params.productId);
    
      watch(productIdToLoad, (v) => {
        items = useProduct({ productId: v });
      });
    
      return { items }
    
    }
```